# Complex Vertices of a square

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The vertices of a square are $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and $z_4$ taken in the anti clockwise order, then what would be $z_3$?

1) $-iz_1+(1+i)z_2$

2) $iz_1+(1+i)z_2$

3) $z_1+(1+i)z_2$

4) $(1+i)z_1+z_2$

Please can someone illustrate this answer with the help of a diagram. I'm having problem with the visualization of the problem.

Comment: you have 4 equations and can find the real and imaginary components for Z1 and Z2.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Use Z=a+ib where I is the $\sqrt{-1}$. You have two such - 2 a's and 2 b's

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $Z_2 Z_3$ would be $Z_1 Z_2$ rotated $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise 
$\iff z_3-z_2 = i(z_2-z_1)$.

Comment: Thus answer 1. I think it would be more pedagogical to write $z_3-z_2 = -i(z_1-z_2)$

Comment: @JeanMarie I can see your point, guess you mean that visualizing it as a rotation around a common vertex may be easier to follow. Maybe, but on the other hand it could also be argued that visualizing all edges as oriented along the counterclockwise order of the vertices makes a lot of sense, and allows for example to relate edges that don't have a common vertex e.g. $z_4-z_3=-(z_2-z_1)$. Of course, they all reduce to the same algebraic equalities in the end.